# I have just one working Wifi connection

Tags: wireless, networking, connection, internet-connection

After configuring my Computer for PXE installation (as a Server). I have only one working internet connection via my home Wifi. The configuration was followed by [PXE Install server Community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer). Actually i can connect my computer to other routers too but i have no internet connection. How is it possible? Any ideas how can i remove the PXE stuff and recover the "Factory settings" for the network?

Answer (score 0):

In all probability you had to shift your client from using DHCP to using a static IP when you installed the DHCP server.  While it's not technically not impossible to run a DHCP client and server on the same machine it's generally recommended to keep the machine static.

I would simply shift the machine back to using the DHCP client. It's pretty easy to go back; edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and go:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

...or whatever your wireless interface name is.